# What is this cable? (DVI/VGA/USB)

Tags: usb, connection, vga, dvi, cable

I can't seem to find any information about this cable which can be seen all over eBay. Apparently it looks like a VGA to DVI cable, but I don't get why there also is a USB cable connected to it. Can someone please explain what they are for?

**Here are some links of it:**
http://www.dhgate.com/product/30-5-pin-dvi-m-to-m-15-pin-vga-usb-cable/234549781.html
http://www.ebay.com/itm/6Ft-30-5-Pin-DVI-D-to-VGA-DB15-pin-USB-A-male-LCD-Monitor-Cord-Cable-1-8m-/371032628756?hash=item5663449e14:g:Z88AAOxyjxlTNBwG

The main reason I'm interested is because I have been searching for some USB to DVI cables to connect to a USB hub for a 3 monitor setup. Are those cables meant to be used as USB to DVI?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your last para,. as you note, is off topic. I advise editing it out, or you risk closure.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "USB to DVI cable".  If you want DVI output from USB, you need a USB to DVI video _adapter_ (search for "Dispalylink"). I have NO idea what those linked cables are intended to be used for tho.  KVM perhaps?

Comment: That does look like a KVM cable where the KVM box is what you connect the VGA and USB to for video, mouse, and keyboard, and the DVI M cable is what type of video connection it would connect to on the back of a server. Essentionally, with a KVM device, you can have multiple servers without the need for each to have it's own keyboard, video, and mouse i.e. KVM... This is common in data centers that host multiple servers that need to be accessible at the console so if you have 25 servers you don't need 25 keyboard, 25 monitors, and 25 mice to manage all those from their console.

Comment: your links appear to be dead

Answer (score 1):

The cables you're looking at are [active](http://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/active-vs-passive-cables-switches-splitters/) adapter cables. They contain circuitry that requires an external power source to operate. The USB connector provides that power (and nothing more than that).